# Error: non-standard import "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql" in standard package

Tags: mysql, go

I want to retrieve some data from my database using go language. This is very beginning my code in file main.go

```
package main

import (
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
)

... *(the rest code)*
```

But, I got error:

```
C:\Go\src\iwantto\main.go:6:2: non-standard import "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql" in standard package "iwantto"
```

I already doing some research in google and forum, but there nothing much about that import. Or, is it really a bug from go language itself?

Comment: It sounds like you may have put your code under `GOROOT` instead of under `GOPATH` where it belongs.

Comment: Indeed. my bad for creating project on `goroot` . the more I know, thankyou @Adrian

Answer (score 2):

When you need your code to do something that might have been implemented by someone else (in Github or somewhere else package), You should initialize go mod file inside of your folder.

For the purposes of this understand, just use example.com/module.

```
go mod init example.com/module
```

Add new module requirements and sums.

```
go mod tidy
```

Run your program

```
go run .
```

For more details:  https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/getting-started